# How to remove stich appearance in phaser tilesprite scroll?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using tilesprite to scroll horizontally but i get a stiched appearance like 2 images are stiched or glued , how can i remove this appearance?, i tried all sorts of resizing but still the stich appearance is present.

Comment: Can you give us anything else to go on (relevant code or even a screenshot)? Also, if you put two of the tiles side-by-side in Photoshop or something similar, are there stitches then? It could just be that the images themselves aren't tiled properly

Comment: yes you are right, my image isn't tiled hence i got stiched appearance, after sometime i converted my image in to tileable image & everything is working fine now thanks!!